# Compile library for all ARM architectures generically using GCC

Tags: gcc, arm, static-libraries, cross-compiling, cpu-architecture

Is there a compile option for GCC that will let me compile a static library for all ARM versions generically? Or at least get multiple architectures in a single compile operation?

New to ARM, and the documentation isn't exactly jumping out at me to answer this question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all ARM versions"? Architecture versions (ARMv4, ARMv7, etc)? Architecture profiles (e.g. ARMv7-A vs ARMv7-M)? Instruction sets (ARM(A32) vs. Thumb(T32) vs. A64)? You've every right to be confused by the horrible mess of it all, but it would certainly help to explain what underlying goal you're actually trying to achieve here - do you really want to produce multiple different binaries, or a single binary that runs on as many things as possible?

Comment: I understood as "a single binary that runs on as many things as possible?" and started to reply. Then saw you and retreated :)

Comment: @Notlikethat - A single binary that runs on as many things as possible would be the goal.  Other than that, I have a lot more investigating to do just based on your question to my question.

Comment: @Notelikethat - To help clarify...Say I want to sell a static library for various ARM chipsets.  I'd wouldn't want to try and build a binary for every single ARM architecture, profile, or instruction set if there was a way to lump most of it in one or a few binaries.

Comment: For a given ABI, there's normally a lowest common denominator that's safe to target, but bear in mind that "various ARM chipsets" potentially covers everything from [teeny tiny microcontrollers](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-processors/lpc-cortex-m-mcus/lpc-cortex-m0-plus-m0/lpc800-low-cost-cortex-m0-plus/low-cost-32-bit-microcontroller-mcu-based-on-arm-cortex-m0-plus-core:LPC810M021FN8?) to [top-end supercomputers](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/06/20/fujitsu_arm_supercomputer/) so you're going to have to narrow it down somewhat ;)

Comment: I would add that at some point you will **have to** to read on "the horrible mess of it all", if not in detail than just to get the picture of what is what, what is compatible with what and so on. Can someone point the OP to some sort of a concise compilation of arch versions, instruction sets, etc? I don't remember ever seeing such a document but then I never really needed it...

Comment: ARM really made a mess of things with their instruction sets (especially ARMv7 with optional NEON support). You can reduce the noise by following Android's example. They divide the ARM world into 3 distinct ABIs - a) ARMv5 (pretty much all 'old' ARM systems going back to the beginning of smartphones b) ARMv7 - includes ARMv6 and option NEON instruction support c) ARMv8 - assumed to be 64-bit

Comment: @Notlikethat - Thanks for the answer!  I'd be on the teeny tiny micros (M3 and 4); so that narrows it down a lot.  But what do companies do (best practice wise) to sell binaries for various ARM architectures.  Is it best to just sell the source code, or compile a binary for every architecture / instruction set / profile / indianess, or just pick a platform to sell your software on (embedded wise)?  Or some other method that I'm oblivious to?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your libraries to run efficiently then they will need to be compiled for specific architectures. For example Cortex M0 code will run on and M3 but M3 code will not run on a M0 (The M0 is a ARMv6m architecture whereas M3 is a ARMv7m architecture). If your libraries use floating point then you will also have to consider this.